# How to stop a while loop? C#

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# and while loops. Does anyone know how to stop it? It keeps printing the first if-statement. Here is the code:

```
   const int Year = 400;
   const int LeapYear = 4;
   const int NoLeapYear = 100;
   int input = 0;
   input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   while (input != 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
       if (input > 0 && input % LeapYear == 0 || input % Year == 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"{input} is a leap year.");
       }
       if (input > 0 && input % NoLeapYear != 0)
       {
            Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not a leap year.");
       }
       if (input < 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Year must be positive!");
       }
       if (input == 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("End of program");
       }
   }
```

Comment: 0 and enter and it will stop. `input != 0` means it will run until(while) the input is not zero. You also have to put the `input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` line inside the while loop.

Comment: the while statement literally says "run while input does not equal zero", so the conclusion is that it will stop as soon as input is 0

Comment: Add `break;` after the 'end of program' printout. Make it a `do/while` loop, and move `input = int.Parse(...)` code inside the loop.

Comment: I don't think this code needs a loop at all. You should also consider elseif for 2nd, 3rd and 4th if.

Answer (score 3):

You have to read the input inside the while loop:

```
const int Year = 400;
const int LeapYear = 4;
const int NoLeapYear = 100;
int input = -1; // initialize to something different than zero, to enter the while loop (or use do while loop instead of while loop)
while (input != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // you were missing this line
    if (input > 0 && input % LeapYear == 0 || input % Year == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{input} is a leap year.");
    }
    if (input > 0 && input % NoLeapYear != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not a leap year.");
    }
    if (input < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Year must be positive!");
    }
    if (input == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End of program");
    }
}
```

Consider using a do while loop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using loop just and break to true statement It will breaks it

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input != 0) {
    conditions;
    break; // Breaks the loop
}
```

Use the `break;` keyword to stop any loop in C# not just C# in many languages also break is used to stop loops

Or,

Satisfy the condition to opposite of what you have it will break/stop the loop

Answer (score 0):

use `break` (https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_break.php)

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
  i++;
  if (i == 4) 
  {
    break;
  }
}
```